# If long content in datagridviewcell(textbox) show right characters

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

in my textcell of a Datagridview the right characters are more importent than the left one. But if the cell is too small for the hole text it just shows some characters beginning from the left side. But I want the right characters.

Is there a possibility to let the right characters have a higher priority to be shown than the left characters?

Comment: Can't you just align the whole column to right?

Comment: The property "align" doesn't work if the text is larger than the cell.